# How to detect when a page gets updated with PHP

Tags: php, scripting

I was wondering how to detect when a page gets updated with PHP. I've researched things on Google, but came across nothing.

What I want to do is call a specific function when a page gets updated. I will be running a cron job in order to run the code.

I want something like this:

```
if (page updated) {
//functions
}
else
{
//functions
}
```

If I can't do something like that then I want to at least know how to detect when a page gets updated with PHP. Please help!

Comment: `if ($old_text != $new_text)`?

Comment: How so? Do you want to check if a table has been updated or do you just want to add a listener class in your PHP code or what?

Comment: Remember - PHP is *server side*.  "Page updates" are *browser side*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.file-get-contents.php) to get the page's content, create a MD5 hash from it, and compare it with the hash you already have. I suggest storing this hash in a simple file.

```
$contents = file_get_contents('http://site.com/page');
$hash     = file_get_contents('hash'); // the text file where the hash is stored
if ($hash == ($pageHash = md5($contents))) {
  // the content is the same
} else {
  // the page has been updated, do whatever you need to do
  // and store the new hash in the file
  $fp = fopen('hash', 'w');
  fwrite($fp, $pageHash);
  fclose($fp);
}
```

Don't forget setting [allow_url_fopen](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) to *On*.

Comment: I think that might work, I'm going to try it. Thank you so much!

Comment: be careful, as some hosts may not allow this sort of remote file access, causing faulty behavior

Comment: It worked, thank you so much! I just have another question, how would I detect what got updated? What I mean is that when the file gets updated, a new line gets added. How do I detect the new line that has been added?

Comment: Glad it worked. -- strcmp() might be what you need. But I don't know how good it would work on a big HTML file. Good luck! :)

Comment: Is there a way that "hash" file can instead hold the actual text of the file? Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: @Gokhan137 Of course, simply do `fwrite(fopen('contents', 'w'), $contents)` to store the page's content in a file called *contents*.

Comment: I recommend call `fclose()`..

Comment: Thanks @TheMask, I updated it.

Comment: I was working on a similar problem.. with this technique on a simple site I was getting a different hash every time despite no real changes. I think dynamically generated tag ids were causing it

Answer (score 2):

You could, as you said, run a cron every hour or 15 minutes or whatever. It will have to access that page, get its modified date, compare it with a stored value, and if it's different, do something.
Obviously, you'd need to update your info, and set the page's current date as $last_set_date or whatever. (It should be done in a database)

This quick snippet grabs a page's last update time (here's more info on that topic: [PHP documentation for get_headers](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php)):

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.example.com';
$h = get_headers($url, TRUE);
echo "LAST MODIFIED: ", $h["Last-Modified"];
?>
```

After you get this, all you need to do is compare it to a previous value which is stored however you like (text file, database) and see if it's different. That's the `page updated` check in your script!

Feel free to give me more clarifications through the comments, and I'll try to improve my answer.

Comment: The giant limitation here is that you're expecting the server on the other side to provide a Last-Modified header, and an accurate one at that. Lots of servers do not provide this header, and if they do, it's unclear what exactly they would be reading to populate it.

Answer (score 0):

**You cannot simply detect if page has been updated using php, try using javascript instead**

Here I assumed you included jquery libray:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $( document ).ready( function(){
        $("#someElementInYourPageYouWannaWatch").change( function(){
          $.ajax({
            url:'http://yourwebsite.php/your_controller.php',
            ...
            success: function( response ){
              $("#someNotifyElement).html('updated');
            }
          });

        });
     });
</script>
```

Something like that :)

Comment: I don't think this response is accurate. You can check with PHP if a page has been detected. See the other replies above.

Comment: Yep, incorrect. This can (and probably should, depending) be done entirely in PHP.