# Hide Content from MD5 PHP

Tags: php, hash, md5

I would like to hide a content(time) from MD5. I plan to get the md5 of a page eg. `md5(file_get_contents("/path/to/file"))`however, it's a dynamic PHP page with ever-changing timestamps, how do I hide the timestamps from md5 so as not to generate different md5 hashes as i plan on using it to check for content changes(comparing it with previous md5 hashes) in which timestamp changes do not count as content changes. Thanks for reading, apologies if  my terminology is incorrect.

Thanks, Justin

Comment: you can't. md5 hashes everything you pass to it. if you don't want some content hashed, then modify the inputs to remove the content, or set it to a known-text replacement. e.g. temporarily replace that location of the file with all-zeroes or something.

Comment: This has very little to do with MD5, but everything with the page. It's about how to ignore content from the page. Where does the page come from, are you using a scraper?

Comment: Nope, i am not using a scraper, i suppose u are proposing i use a scraper to remover content then return the content after the md5 hash has been generated ? I was actually planning on generating MD5 hash from a page then compare it to the same page later on to check for updates, in relation to this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10668440/how-to-detect-when-a-page-gets-updated-with-php)

Comment: Is there a way to recognize the timestamp? Is it surrounded by div, span?

Comment: Sry for delay @Marek Yes, it is surrounded by <Div> span